# How do I change the 'height' from a geom_error bar? R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

so this is my data:

```
> man
                                   Producto  Unidades Group.3 Promedio Mínimo Máximo
1                      Alquiler montacargas       $/h  Manabí    40.00  30.00  50.00
2                              Aforo Simple     $/TEU  Manabí   145.00 145.00 145.00
3            Consolidación/desconsolidación     $/TEU  Manabí   125.53 125.53 125.53
4 Almacenaje de contenedores de 1 a 10 días $/TEU/día  Manabí     3.57   3.57   3.57
```

And I used this code for the graph:

```
ggplot(man, aes(Promedio, Producto))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin= Mínimo, xmax=Máximo), size=1)+
  geom_point(size=3, colour="deepskyblue")+
  theme_light()+labs(x = "Precio Promedio", y = "Producto",
                     title = "Precio promedio de productos/servicios", subtitle = "Manabí") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 15))+facet_grid(.~Unidades, scales='free')+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

How can I change the height of the vertical lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `geom_errorbar()` layer supports a `width` argument which does this. Try different values:

```
ggplot(man, aes(Promedio, Producto)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = Mínimo, xmax = Máximo), size = 1, width = ___) +
```

Comment: Yes! It worked!! Thank you! Imma check this as the right response asap